# Rewrite URL through .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

My website generates page URL with the prefix `?Script=`, which is not SEO-friendly.

I want to remove this prefix and just keep the page title.

For example, I want to convert the following URL:

`example.com/?Script=about` to `example.com/about`

`about` is the About page of my website.

I want to set up a rule for omitting `?Script=` for all pages.

I have managed to do it for my blog post by using the following rewrite rule.

```
RewriteRule ^news/([0-9a-zA-Z_-]+) ?Script=news_view&uid=$1
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, so you mean you are hitting url `example.com/?Script=about` in browser and you want to redirect(change URL in browser) to `example.com/about`? Kindly confirm on same once.

Comment: Thanks for your concern. My website's core files have **&Script=** attached to its URLs. I want to rewrite this URL **example.com/?Script=about** to **example.com/about** this one so that when I hit **example.com/about** it doesn't show me a 404 error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for you .

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^(about)/?$ /?script?=$1 [L]
```

If you have more pages , you can add those pages to the pattern

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^(about|page2|page3)/?$ /?script?=$1 [L]
```